# Can an endpoint ignore the 'after request' decorator in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

If I have a function

```
@app.after_request
def foo():
    ....
```

which is used after *almost* every request, but not for some, can I ignore the above for some requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this -

```
@app.after_request
def foo():
    if request.endpoint != 'endpoint' :
        .... your code
    else:
        return
```

Here replace `'endpoint'` with the endpoints you want to skip